# Chrome Addressbar invisible

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently i found out that after resizing my chrome browser during testing with the inspector open, my address / URL bar disappears unfindable. although while opening a new tab i can enter URLs normally since the url bar gets autofocused, but the bar is still invisible. Does anybody know **why** this happens or how to disable this *feature*  / **bug**.

Has anybody else seen this before, or is it just me? 
[image: chrome bug]

Help appreciated, thx

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue as of late. While I have not found a solution in the Chrome stable channel, switching over to Chrome Canary seems to be a valid interim fix. Of course, there could be some bug happening in one of my extensions that aren't present, but this is allowing me to get some work done.

Comment: that is an idea, but i don't wanna change to canary since it is still beta.

Comment: Understandably so. It's an alright fix for me because I'm conscious of what browser capabilities are well supported, and that although I'm using Canary for efficient coding I do still need to test against stable browsers. One troubleshooting approach I might suggest is to disable all of your extensions, see if the problem is solved, then re-enable them gradually until it presents itself again.

Comment: I answered here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210027/google-chrome-address-bar-disappears-on-resize/29370960#29370960)