# Google Chrome address bar disappears on resize

Tags: google-chrome

With the latest version of Google Chrome (Versión 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)) running on MacOSX Yosemite, when I resize the address bar I loose the bar and I've to restart Google Chrome.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMKfWONS_FI

It's a really bad thing when you've to develop web applications for small devices. 
Any ideas? Has anyone found a posible workaround?

Comment: This is not a work around for the problem itself, but for the use case of testing for small devices, you now have device (and viewport size) emulation available in Chrome Developer Tools by default when you hit `Command + Option + I`.

Comment: I have the same problem! The only difference is I come across the bug a different way. But it has to do with resizing the browser and my application buttons moving in a way that makes the address bar hide and then it never comes back.

Comment: Press Command+L to grab the address bar if you need to change the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the official bug thread for this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8663

Apparently, for some users the following solved the issue:

1. Open Chrome Settings
2. Select "Show Advanced Settings"
3. Scroll down to "System"
4. Un-check "Use hardware acceleration when available"

**[UPDATE]**
at the beginning it was working for me.. but not it seemed not working anymore.

Comment: Is this the right bug report? This bug report seems to be about 'Don't get status-bar on hovering over a link'

Answer (score 1):

btw i found a solution or at least the problem to this one:

In [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082758/chrome-addressbar-invisible) i had too many plugins installed, and when i resized the browser to a minimum the plugins took away all of the space from the addressbar. therefore it got sort of invisible and while resizing the window to a larger screen chrome sort of *forgot* that it had made the address bar invisible.. so i removed some plugins from the toolbar and since then i haven't had a problem anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Google knows about this. I submitted the question on their community forums where there were tons of questions when the little double arrow that allowed you to resize the address bar on Chrome suddenly disappeared. They never answered, not even when I submitted a feedback. I found someone who gave a solution using the chrome://flags settings. It worked and I was able to resize again until recently on another of the never-ending updates they again cancelled the ability. They know about it and refuse to tell us. The next time someone finds how to fix this, I'm starting a file of fixes that Google purposely hides form users with the claim that they are for a better user experience. It's not.